# How can I ensure that every page within my drupal 6 site loads a specific Javascript file?

Tags: 6, theming

I want to include the sites/all/themes/fusion/mapsindeed/js/css3-mediaqueries.js
 file so that mediaqueries will work within Internet Explorer 8 and below, like it already does for other web browsers.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the URL of the JavaScript file as `scripts[]` to the theme's [info file](http://drupal.org/node/171205#scripts).